# create li according to a php array with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I get from my database a PHP array that looks like this:

```
     $dbResult= array([0]=>array([a]=>1 [b]=>1 [c]=>1)
                      [1]=>array([a]=>2 [b]=>2 [c]=>2)
                      [3]=>array([a]=>3 [b]=>3 [c]=>3)
                     )
```

And in my HTML Ihave a div with the id `class`.

What i would like to do is create a table with that PHParray using JavaScript but only when  label id="labletocreatetable" is clicked, the table should look like this

```
a b c
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3
```

i know that i should use json_encode but when i do that the result looks like this and im not pretty sure how to use it

```
[{"a":"1","b":"1","c":"1"},
 {"a":"2","b":"2","c":"2"},
 {"a":"3","b":"3","c":"3"}]
```

Comment: How did you get it in your `JavaScript`, is that already available ?

Comment: Maybe think about transforming the data and then displaying it. For example it looks like the data is horizontal write a function to restructure the array and then display it. It will be a lot easier to display then.

Comment: cant really restructure the php array because each line belongs to a record in the database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = [
    {"a":"1","b":"1","c":"1"},
    {"a":"2","b":"2","c":"2"},
    {"a":"3","b":"3","c":"3"}
], cols = [];

// Elements to clone:
var tr = document.createElement('tr'),
    td = document.createElement('td');

function addCell(text, row) {
    var cell = td.cloneNode(false);
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    row.appendChild(cell);
}

// Body:
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody')
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
    var row = tr.cloneNode(false);

    // Iterate known columns
    for(var j=0; j<cols.length; ++j) {
        addCell(arr[i][cols[j]], row);
        delete arr[i][cols[j]]; // Warning: will erase data
    }

    // Find new columns
    for(var j in arr[i]) {
        if(arr[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
            cols.push(j);
            addCell(arr[i][j], row);
        }
    }

    tbody.appendChild(row);
}

// Head:
var thead = document.createElement('thead'),
    row = tr.cloneNode(false);
for(var i=0; i<cols.length; ++i) {
    addCell(cols[i], row);
}
thead.appendChild(row);

// Table:
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xna5/2/).

The problem with your structure is that we don't know the columns beforehand, and that `for..in` iterates objects in arbitrary order.

Then, I created an array to store the columns in order, and for each row I first iterate those columns, and then iterate remaining ones (in any order) and push them to the array.

If you don't want to erase data, here is an [alternative demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xna5/1/).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you wanted but this might helps you

```
<?php

 $dbResult= array(0=>array('a'=>1, 'b'=>1, 'c'=>1),
                      1=>array('a'=>2, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>2),
                      3=>array('a'=>3, 'b'=>3, 'c'=>3)
                     );
echo '<table border=1><tr><td>';
echo implode('<td>',array_keys($dbResult[0]));  

 foreach($dbResult as $k =>$v){
    echo '<tr>';
foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
    echo '<td>'.$v1.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
```

***output***

[image]

Comment: thanks for the effor but that is using php and i need to do it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ajax for this purpose. I have written the steps.

1) a.html

--Include jQuery library--

```
<div id="div1"></div> <!-- DIV WHERE THE TABLE CONTENT WILL BE LOADED -->
<label id="labletocreatetable" onclick="createTheTable()">Click to create the table</label>


<script>
function createTheTable() {

  $.ajax({
    url:"<Path to >get_the_content.php",
    success:function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result); // DIV WHERE THE CONTENT WILL BE LOADED
    }
    });

}
</script>
```

2) get_the_content.php

```
<?php $dbResult= array(
           0=>array('a'=>1, 'b'=>1, 'c'=>1),
                   1=>array('a'=>2, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>2),
                   3=>array('a'=>3, 'b'=>3, 'c'=>3),
                ); 
$myKeys = array_keys($dbResult[0]); //Will return you a,b,c as numeric array.  ?>


<table border="1" width="30%">
 <tr> <!-- FOR THE TABLE HEADER a,b and c -->
    <th> <?php echo $myKeys[0]; ?> </th>
    <th> <?php echo $myKeys[1]; ?> </th>
    <th> <?php echo $myKeys[2]; ?> </th>
  </tr>
<?php foreach($dbResult as $key=>$rows) { // for the table's content ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $rows[$myKeys[0]]; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $rows[$myKeys[1]]; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $rows[$myKeys[2]]; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table> 

<!-- YOU NEEDN'T TO echo THE TABLE it will be automatically returned to ajax. -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwvLG/2/)):

```
// Set this with PHP
var data =  [{"a":"1","b":"1","c":"1"},
             {"a":"2","b":"2","c":"2"},
             {"a":"3","b":"3","c":"3"}];

// Set this to the target html element
var target = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

// Create table and add header
var table  = createElement('table');
    table.appendChild( addRow( Object.keys(data[0]) ) );

// Add rows
for (var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
    table.appendChild( addRow( data[r] ) );
}

// Append table to target
target.appendChild(table);

// Helper functions
function createElement(type, content) {
    var e = document.createElement(type);

    if (typeof content !== "undefined") {
        if (typeof content === "string") {
            content = document.createTextNode(content);
        }

        e.appendChild(content);
    }

    return e;
}

function addRow( rowData ) {
    var tr = createElement('tr');

    for (var key in rowData) {
        tr.appendChild( createElement('td', rowData[key]) );
    }

    return tr;
}
```

All you need to do is set **data** and **target**.